# Python tkinter - How to make two linked combo boxes using a dictionary

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

Aim: Two linked combo boxes, one displays the dictionary keys. The other displays the values of the selected keys.

I have got as far as populating the first combo box with the values of the dictionary keys, converted to a list so it displays nicely in the combo box.
A default value has been set which is used to gather the required data for the second combo box. All is working well here, the area where I have got stuck is how to update the
values in the second combo box when the first combo box current value is changed.

Code so far

```
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, ttk

dict_values = {
    "Beer": ["Ale", "Lager", "Stout"],
    "Spirits": ["Brandy", "Gin", "Rum"],
    "Wine": ["White","Red","Rose"]
}

#convert keys to list for displaying in the first combobox
box1= []
for key in dict_values:
    box1.append(key)

from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, ttk

class Application:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.combo()
        
    def combo(self):
        #First Combobox
        self.box_value = StringVar()
        self.box = ttk.Combobox(self.parent, textvariable=self.box_value, 
                                state='readonly')
        self.box['values'] = box1
        self.box.current(0)
        self.box.grid(column=0, row=0)
        
        #Second Combobox
        self.box_value2 = StringVar()
        self.box2 = ttk.Combobox(self.parent, textvariable=self.box_value2, 
                                state='readonly')
        self.box2['values'] = dict_values[self.box.get()]
      
        self.box2.grid(column=1, row=0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.minsize(800, 600) 
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is missing binding the `<<ComboboxSelected>>` event to a callback that will be executed when a selection is made in `self.box`

So add

`self.box.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",self.selected)` Note that `self.selected` is the new method you'll have to implement, here is an example

```py
    def selected(self,e):
        #print('selected value ->',self.box.get(),self.box_value.get())
        self.box2.configure(values = dict_values[self.box_value.get()] )
        self.box2.current(0)
```

Entire Code

```py
#<<ComboboxSelected>>
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, ttk

dict_values = {
    "Beer": ["Ale", "Lager", "Stout"],
    "Spirits": ["Brandy", "Gin", "Rum"],
    "Wine": ["White","Red","Rose"]
}

#convert keys to list for displaying in the first combobox
box1= []
for key in dict_values:
    box1.append(key)

from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, ttk

class Application:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.combo()

    # Modification 2
    def selected(self,e):
        #print('selected value ->',self.box.get(),self.box_value.get())
        self.box2.configure(values = dict_values[self.box_value.get()] )
        self.box2.current(0)


    def combo(self):
        #First Combobox
        self.box_value = StringVar()
        self.box = ttk.Combobox(self.parent, textvariable=self.box_value,
                                state='readonly')
        # Modification 1
        self.box.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",self.selected)
        self.box['values'] = box1
        self.box.current(0)
        self.box.grid(column=0, row=0)

        #Second Combobox
        self.box_value2 = StringVar()
        self.box2 = ttk.Combobox(self.parent, textvariable=self.box_value2,
                                state='readonly')
        self.box2['values'] = dict_values[self.box.get()]

        self.box2.grid(column=1, row=0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.minsize(800, 600)
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you that is awesome! I will do some reading up on <<ComboboxSelected>>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `validate` and `validatecommand` to accomplish this. There is no need to add a `bind` to the Combobox. `validatecommand` will run every time you click the Combobox if `validate` is set to `"all"` or `"focus"`.

A `StringVar` is unnecessary overhead and the structure of your document is a bit strange. The example below addresses those issues and provides the solution to your question.

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

class Application(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self,  *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.options = {
            "Beer": ["Ale", "Lager", "Stout"],
            "Spirits": ["Brandy", "Gin", "Rum"],
            "Wine": ["White","Red","Rose"]
        }
        
        #delegate between init and config so the Combobox kwargs are not a mile long
        self.cb1 = Combobox(self, state="readonly", values=[*self.options])
        self.cb1.config(validate="focus", validatecommand=self.populate_slave)
        
        self.cb1.current(0)
        self.cb1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        
        self.cb2 = Combobox(self, state="readonly")
        self.cb2.grid(column=1, row=0)

        #manually run the validatecommand function once to init cb2 items
        #this way it will always be correct regardless of the item you start cb1 with
        self.populate_slave() 
        
    def populate_slave(self):
        self.cb2['values'] = self.options[self.cb1.get()]
        self.cb2.current(0)
        return True #must return True or validatecommand will quit
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.minsize(800, 600)
    app.title('My Application')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, points taken. I will use this as a study to optimise my code